# How to show images in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display small images with HTML and javascript, but don't know why it's not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Show the images</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="smallPhotos">
        <ul id="smallPhotosList">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <script scr="img.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code:

```
//img.js  
 var ul =  document.getElementById("smallPhotosList");

    for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = '<img src="photo0'+i+'.jpg" width="80" height="50">';
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

All 6 images (photo01....photo06) and code files are in the same directory.

Comment: what does the code do? does it throw any error?

Comment: @Plastic nothing, just an empty page have no errors

Comment: @casper definitely, your image path is wrong. Otherwise your code might not be the best way to do so but it is fine, See [the related snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091837/6320039).

Comment: @UlysseBN that's really weird, I definitely checked the path first. The path is correct. But still not showing, I found other ways to show it. Just VERY curious why this way doesn't work on my machine. Not sure if it's environment independent

Comment: You may be referencing a relative path from a nested resource whereas your image is in some other asset path? To debug such a thing I'd suggest moving the images or changing the path until either gives you something. And start from there to debug further!

Comment: nope, all are in the same folder. I will continue to dig further. Thnx anyway !

Comment: I could help you a lot more if you could bring a [mre] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing your question to make it a snippet and got the answer right away. I don't think there is any issue with your code.

```js
var ul =  document.getElementById("smallPhotosList");

for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x50.png?text='+i+'" width="80" height="50">';
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div id="smallPhotos">
    <ul id="smallPhotosList">

    </ul>
</div>
```

One possible issue left might be that the photos are not available!

**NOTE:** this should be a comment but I really wanted to include this snippet which speaks by itself.

---

A better way to do it though would be to construct all your DOM elements with JavaScript, which is faster and less error-prone:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("smallPhotosList")

for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li")
    var img = document.createElement("img")
    // If IE is no issue, prefer:
    //   var img = new Image()
    img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/80x50.png?text=' + i
    img.width = 80
    img.height = 50
    li.appendChild(img)
    ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; }
li { display: inline-block; margin: 1px; }
```

```html
<div id="smallPhotos">
    <ul id="smallPhotosList">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

html:

```
<div id="your-image"></div>
```

js:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.src = "image.png";
var src = document.getElementById("your-image");

src.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new element and add its source in a generic way and then add it to li then add that li to ul

```
var ul =  document.getElementById("smallPhotosList");

    for(var i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src = `images${i}.jpg`;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(elem);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

Comment: Thnx )) But, is my method has a mistake ? I just don't get it why it doesn't work, seems like legit code

Answer (score 0):

I run your code with keeping images in same folder. Everything works fine. Check your images if properly named as `photo01.jpg, photo02.jpg, photo03.jpg`...